# Get host mount directory from within Docker container

Tags: docker, mount-point

I am running a Python application in a Docker container.  The application downloads files to `container_dir` in the container.  I mount that `container_dir` to a `host_dir` on the host at runtime, e.g.

`docker run ... --mount type=bind,source=host_dir,target=container_dir`

The application running in the container will see files at `container_dir` and return that file path.  However, the files get written to `host_dir` by virtue of the `--mount` instruction and so I would like the Python application to see (and report) the "de-referenced" `host_dir` instead of `container_dir`.  Is that possible ?  I'm thinking since Docker knows about the mount then applications running in the container should be able to know about it too.

I tried mounting to a Docker volume instead.  I also tried `--network=host` in case that had some relation even though I did not think so.

TIA

Comment: If the host filesystem is a critical part of your service's operation – you need to write files there and return their host-native paths – would it make more sense to run it in something like a Python virtual environment, without Docker, that wouldn't have a fully isolated filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass the `host_dir` as an env variable using the -e flag and use it as the basepath for your downloaded files instead of `container_dir`:

```
docker run -e HOST_FOLDER=host_dir ....
```